# Can anyone see why my excel sheet is pushing out a Runtime error 13 Type Mismatch for the below code?

Tags: excel, runtime

> If ws.Cells(sourceSheetStartColumn, sourceSheetEndColumn - 1) = ""
>   Then GoTo Here '

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks Pedro. I read the guide but honestly I have no idea what I'm asking about so I put it in plain simple english. Someone else wrote this code and I'm running into an error using it. Just hoping someone understand what the issue is.

Comment: it's impossible for us to help you with such limited information.

Comment: ok can you help provide you with better information? What should I share with you?

Comment: Update your question.

Comment: Can you provide a reasonable snapshot of the rest of the code (not all of it, but maybe how the variables in this line get assigned)?

Answer (score 0):

The error means you are using one of your variable in a manner that does not fit its type.  Specifically:

```
If ws.Cells(sourceSheetStartColumn, sourceSheetEndColumn - 1) = "" Then GoTo Here '
```

means that:

1. `ws` is a Worksheet
2. `sourceSheetStartColumn` and `sourceSheetEndColumn` are numbers

Check your code to ensure these are declared correctly.  Here is an example where this should cause no issues:

```
Sub Foo()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim sourceSheetStartColumn, sourceSheetEndColumn As Integer

  Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  sourceSheetStartColumn = 2
  sourceSheetEndColumn = 2

  If ws.Cells(sourceSheetStartColumn, sourceSheetEndColumn - 1) = "" Then GoTo Here '

  MsgBox ("Checkpoint 1")

Here:

  MsgBox ("Checkpoint 2")

End Sub
```

So, were I to change your source and end columns to a `String` and assign values of "A" and "B" to them, I would get your Runtime Error 13.

Answer (score 0):

You will get *Run-time error 13* if the cell you are trying to access has an error.

e.g. Cell A1 has formula `=NA()`

in the immediate window,

```
?cells(1,1)
```

gives

> Error 2042

if you try to compare this value to anything, you will get `Type Mismatch`